# Convert a character array of binary numbers into a counter of Gray Code in C++

Tags: c++, c, gray-code

is there any way to convert a char array of binary number into Gray Code. For example, I have the following code:

```
int j;
char binaryNum[10], *pointer;
/* From Hex convert to decimal */
j = strtol( str, &pointer, 16);
/* From Decimal convert to Binary */
itoa(j, binaryNum, 2);
cout<<"Binary form of Y = "<<binaryNum<<"\n";
```

What i want is to convert this binaryNum into Gray Code, i.e change it one bit at a time. Can somebody please help me with the code ?
forexample, i have a char binaryNum[10] == 101101
and i want to convert it to gray code, i.e change only one bit at a time, like:
101100
101110
101111
something like  thiss..

Comment: Is this homework? What all have you tried so far ?

Comment: no, its basically a long code. this is just a snippet of what. What i am not understanding is that, how to change only one bit at a time and generate series, like its done in gray's code? i can convert it to array of intergers but what next?

Comment: See Oli's answer below - it's very easy to convert an integer to its corresponding Gray Code representation

Comment: i want to do something like, for example i have a char binaryNum[10] == 101101 and i want to convert it to gray code, i.e change only one bit at a time, like: 101100 101110 101111 something like thiss..

Answer (score 4):

It can be as simple as:

```
x_gray = x ^ (x >> 1);
```

Comment: @bijlikamasla: Sounds like you need to go look up [bitwise operators in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators). That's not exponentiation.

Comment: i want to do something like, for example i have a char binaryNum[10] == 101101 and i want to convert it to gray code, i.e change only one bit at a time, like: 101100 101110 101111 something like thiss.

Comment: @bijilk: That doesn't make any sense.  Are you just asking for a gray-code counter?

Comment: yeah, sort of, but for char array.. not integer array.

Comment: @bijilk: Then please update your question to make it clear *exactly* what you're trying to do.  If you want to make a counter, then *say so*!